# How to log single SQL table using NLog in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, logging, nlog

I am trying to log the single table using NLog bypassing parameter values into each column using NLog. But somehow I couldn't able to log in to the SQL table.

I tried by passing values by passing code like this and added the targets and rules in web.config.

Code in the class

```
private static Logger _logger;

public CustomToken()
{
    _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("apiUsageLogger");
}

_logger.Info("{clientname}", "test");
_logger.Info($"clientusername", "test");
_logger.Info($"route", "test");
_logger.Info($"parameters", "test");
_logger.Info($"isuserauthenticated", 1);
```

In the web.config

```
<target name="apiUsageLog" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="connStringName">
        <commandtext>
          INSERT INTO Table
          (ClientName, ClientUserName, Route, Parameters, IsUserAuthenticated, Machine)
          VALUES
          (@clientname, @clientusername, @route, @parameters, @isuserauthenticated, @machine)
        </commandtext>
        <parameter name="@clientname" layout="${clientname}" />
        <parameter name="@clientusername" layout="${clientusername}" />
        <parameter name="@route" layout="${route}" />
        <parameter name="@parameters" layout="${parameters}" />
        <parameter name="@isuserauthenticated" layout="${isuserauthenticated}" />
        <parameter name="@machine" layout="${machinename}" />
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <<logger name="apiUsageLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="apiUsageLog" />
    </rules>
```

Somehow data is not getting populated into the table.

Is there a way I can able to achieve in populating the data into appropriate columns? NLog is the right way of doing it?

Comment: What framework are you using and what version of NLog?

Comment: @EdneyHolder I think 4.6.2 version we are using.

Comment: OK that handles the first part of the question. What version of NLog are you using?

Comment: @EdneyHolder NLog version is 4.6.2 and Framework version is 4.6.1.

`<package id="NLog" version="4.6.2" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="NLog.Extended" version="4.6.2" targetFramework="net461" />`

Comment: Please note, there is also a XML error in your config ` <<logger ` should be `<logger`. Not sure if that's a copy mistake here.

Comment: @Julian Yeah it is a copy mistake. `<logger name="apiUsageLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="apiUsageLog"  final="true"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's clear, but with database target one log message will be one record in the database. I would recommend to read [the tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial). Also in this case the [database target options](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) are good to check.

Your config isn't working as `${clientusername}` doesn't exist in NLog.

I will show 3 examples, hope that make things clear

#### Example 1: simple logs to database target

Logger call:

```
logger.Info("my info message");
```

config:

```xml
<target name="apiUsageLog" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="connStringName">
    <commandtext>
        INSERT INTO Table
        (message, machinename)
        VALUES
        (@message, @machinenameParam)
    </commandtext>
    <parameter name="@messageParam" layout="${message}" /> <!-- this will be "my info message"-->
    <parameter name="@machinenameParam" layout="${machinename}" /> <!-- defined in NLog, see https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers-->
    </target>
</targets>
```

This will create a log record in the database with `my info message` and the machine name.

#### Example 2: with custom properties:

I will use structured logging here. See [structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging)

Logger call:

```
logger.Info("my info message with {Property1}", "value1");
```

config:

```xml
<target name="apiUsageLog" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="connStringName">
    <commandtext>
        INSERT INTO Table
        (message, machinename, property1)
        VALUES
        (@message, @machinenameParam, @propertyParam1)
    </commandtext>
    <parameter name="@messageParam" layout="${message}" /> <!-- this will be "my info message"-->
    <parameter name="@machinenameParam" layout="${machinename}" /> <!-- defined in NLog, see https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers-->
    <parameter name="@propertyParam1" layout="${event-properties:Property1}" /> <!-- this will be "value1" -->
    </target>
</targets>
```

This will create a log record in the database with `my info message with "Value1"` , the machine name and the custom property with "value1".

#### Example 3: custom properties, not all in the message

This combines structured logging and `WithProperty`. You need at least NLog 4.6.3 for this.

Logger call:

```cs
logger.WithProperty("Property2", "value2")
      .Info("my info message {Property1}", "value1");
```

config:

```xml
<target name="apiUsageLog" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="connStringName">
    <commandtext>
        INSERT INTO Table
        (message, machinename, property1, property2)
        VALUES
        (@message, @machinenameParam, @propertyParam2)
    </commandtext>
    <parameter name="@messageParam" layout="${message}" /> <!-- this will be: my info message with "value1"-->
    <parameter name="@machinenameParam" layout="${machinename}" /> <!-- defined in NLog, see https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers-->
    <parameter name="@propertyParam1" layout="${event-properties:Property1}" /> <!-- this will be "value1" -->
    <parameter name="@propertyParam2" layout="${event-properties:Property2}" /> <!-- this will be "value2" -->
    </target>
</targets>
```

This will create a log record in the database with `my info message with "Value1"` , the machine name and the custom properties "value1" and "value2"

Note, now "value1" is in the message and "value2" isn't.